# Definition of x <> ANY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning about SQL and I've bumped into several definitions dealing with sets, like:

```
SELECT x
FROM table t1
WHERE x >= ALL (
    SELECT x
    FROM table t2
)
```

finds the maximum element of the set,

`x <= ALL(...)` finds the minimum element of the data set, `x = ANY (...)` is the same as `x IN (...)`, `x <> ALL(...)` is the same as `x NOT IN(...)`

But I can't figure out if `x <> ANY` means anything at all.

Can you please help me figure out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *means* something, but it's not particularly useful. Straight from the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html):

> The `ANY` keyword, which must follow a comparison operator, means “return `TRUE` if the comparison is `TRUE` for `ANY` of the values in the column that the subquery returns.”

So `x <> ANY` will always be `TRUE` if there are at least two distinct, non-`NULL` elements in the subquery result (since `x` will necessarily be `<>` to at least one of them). EDIT: Unless `x` is `NULL`, since, as @ruakh points out in a comment, `NULL <> anything` is always `FALSE`.

Comment: ok, but what kind of data can I find using `x <> ANY(...)`?
EDIT: so, it's a practically useless operation?

Comment: Not _entirely_ useless, but looks like a very odd way to produce comparison on inequality (because if we have at least _two distinct_ values in set, there will be no such third value which will be equal to both of them because of transitivity principle - thus, `x!= ANY (values set)` will be same as `(values set has at least two distinct values) OR (they all are same && x!=this same value`)

Comment: @AlmaDo: Except for `NULL`, which is neither equal nor unequal to any other value.

Answer (score 0):

`t1.x <> ANY (SELECT t2.x FROM t2)` means the same as `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.x <> t1.x)`; that is, it is true if there's even a single row in `t2` with `t2.x <> t1.x`.